# determine course time conflicted or not

Tags: php, database, database-design

I have to store the course time into database, and the format is like that `3CD5G` or `4EFG`.......etc.
I wonder that how to store it into the database that I can retrieve it to determine whether the selected courses are conflicted or not, because is variable length, I cannot figure out a better way to store it, any advice?
And how do I generate a unique number elaborately for course ID?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Is "3CD5G" some kind of secret code?  Which dbms?

Comment: 3meansThursday andCmeans10:10 ~ 11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store courses as beginning time and last time(+1 second), e.g. zero hour course= [0..3600[ , and make sure your time format can be compared using the mysql and php comparision operators. This should ensure you get the most out of the DB.